# Mongodb (Mongoose) trouble returning array of strings that corresponds to existing Collections in the database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, callback

I have created a helper function that should **return a promise which returns an array of strings representing all of the names of Collections currently in my database**.

I was able to verify through console logging that I am successfully connecting to the database and that my names array is being populated with the expected values, **however calling this method returns undefined**.

How can I modify this to return the expected result?

```
function getCollectionNames() {
    mongoose.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true })
    const db = mongoose.connection

    db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'Connection error:'))

    db.once('open', () => {
        return mongoose.connection.db.listCollections().toArray().then( (collections) => {
            let names = [] 
            collections.forEach( (col) => { names.push(col.name) })
            mongoose.connection.close()
            return names
        }) 
    })
}

getCollectionNames() // Should return an array of strings.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All your DB operations are asynchronous, so when your function returns, this operations are not finished (and maybe not even started).

[This is an article](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/understanding-asynchronous-javascript-callbacks-through-household-chores-e3de9a1dbd04) which is great to understand the way JS handles asynchronous code.

Also you may need to understand [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to understand the code below.

I don't know if you're familiar with `Promise`s, if not, [here's a good link](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/understanding-asynchronous-javascript-callbacks-through-household-chores-e3de9a1dbd04).

Now, I assume that you're familiar with asynchronous code and promises. So, what you need to do is :

- connect to your DB
- retrieve data and process it

First, connect to your db (which is a asynchronous operation) :

```
const mongoose = require( 'mongoose' ); 

// just call it once to connect to your DB
const connectToMongoDB = uri => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  mongoose.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true }); 
  const mongooseCo = mongoose.connection;

  mongooseCo.on('error', err => reject(err))
  mongooseCo.once('open', () => resolve(mongooseCo));
});
```

When this Promise resolves, it means that your DB connection is open (`.once('open')`)

Here's how to use this function :

```
connectToMongoDB(YOUR_DB_URI)
  .then(db => {
    /* do what you want with your db */
  })
  .catch(e => { /* the connection throws an error : e */ })
```

OK, now you need to get data from your DB and retrieve it. The process is the same : create a function that returns a Promise and resolve the Promise to get the value.

```
const getMyCollections = mongooseCo => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  mongooseCo.db.listCollections().toArray().then(collections => {
    const names = collections.map(col => col.name);
    resolve(names);
  })
});
```

Here's how to use it :

```
getMyCollections(mongoose.connection)
  .then(names => { /* Do what you want with your names */ })
```

**Making it work together**

```
connectToMongoDB(YOUR_DB_URI)
  .then(mongooseCo => {
     getMyCollections(mongooseCo)
       .then(names => {
         /* do what you want with your names */
        })
   })
```

Better using [Promise chaining](https://javascript.info/promise-chaining) :

```
connectToMongoDB(YOUR_DB_URI)
  .then(getMyCollections)
  .then(names => {
    /* here are your names */
   })
```

Hope it helps,
Best regards

Comment: This was tremendously helpful and easy to understand!!! Thank you so much. Spent like 3 nights on this... :/

Answer (score 0):

Try running your collection names function after connection.

```
'mongoose.connection.on('open', function (ref) {
    console.log('Connected to mongo server.');
    //trying to get collection names
    mongoose.connection.db.collectionNames(function (err, names) {
        console.log(names); // [{ name: 'dbname.myCollection' }]
        module.exports.Collection = names;
    });
})'
```